# pyspark, new column, mismatch from pattern

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to create a new column called `Check` that will show Mismatch if the value in a group of rows is not the same.

What I have now:

```
data = [
  ("Category2","File1",2,2),
  ("Category2","File2",2,2),
  ("Category2","File3",2,2),
  ("Category2","File4",5,2),
  ("Category1","File1",4,1),
  ("Category1","File2",4,1),
  ("Category1","File3",4,1),
  ("Category1","File4",4,1),
]

cols = ["Category","Filename","count","DistinctCount"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,cols)

df.show()


+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
| Category|Filename|count|DistinctCount|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
|Category2|   File1|    2|            2|
|Category2|   File2|    2|            2|
|Category2|   File3|    2|            2|
|Category2|   File4|    5|            2|
|Category1|   File1|    4|            1|
|Category1|   File2|    4|            1|
|Category1|   File3|    4|            1|
|Category1|   File4|    4|            1|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+---------+
| Category|Filename|count|DistinctCount|    Check|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+---------+
|Category2|   File1|    2|            2|       OK|
|Category2|   File3|    2|            2|       OK|
|Category2|   File2|    2|            2|       OK|
|Category2|   File4|    5|            2| Mismatch|
|Category1|   File1|    4|            1|       OK|
|Category1|   File4|    4|            1|       OK|
|Category1|   File2|    4|            1|       OK|
|Category1|   File3|    4|            1|       OK|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+---------+
```

I'm thinking of using a window function to group the rows by `Category` but stuck on how to think/write the logic for the mismatch.

Thank you!

/B

Comment: what if there are only two rows and they're different?

Comment: the assumption is that there always will be 4 files per category and that they need to be evenly divided in the count.

Comment: If it were to be that all 4 files had different count value, I would like the logic to show Mismatch for all 4 rows.

Comment: what if it's 2 with one value and 2 with another?

Comment: @mck not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: like what if count = 2 for file1 and file2 and count=3 for file3 and file4? then all are mismatch?

Comment: Yes you are correct, then I would like the logic to fill it to be mismatch. Because ultimately the desired count value from the 4 files needs to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

win=Window.partitionBy ('count')

(df.withColumn('UniqueCount',F.count('DistinctCount').over(win))#groupby count and count DistinctCount in eachgroup
 
     .withColumn('UniqueCount',when(F.col('UniqueCount')=='1','mismatch').otherwise('ok'))# Attribute with mismatch if UniqueCount=1, else OK
 
     .orderBy(F.asc('Category'))#Sort dataframe
 
     .show())


+---------+--------+-----+-------------+-----------+

| Category|Filename|count|DistinctCount|UniqueCount|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+-----------+
|Category1|   File1|    4|            1|         ok|
|Category1|   File2|    4|            1|         ok|
|Category1|   File3|    4|            1|         ok|
|Category1|   File4|    4|            1|         ok|
|Category2|   File1|    2|            2|         ok|
|Category2|   File4|    5|            2|   mismatch|
|Category2|   File2|    2|            2|         ok|
|Category2|   File3|    2|            2|         ok|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to calculate per `Category` which value of `count` is ok and which value should be mapped to `Mismatch`.

The data can be grouped by `Category` while collecting the amount of different values in the column `count` per `Category` into a [list](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html). Then the list is [sorted](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html) by this amount in descending order. [If](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#if) the list has size 1, everything is ok. Otherwise we assume that the first element in the list is ok and all others are not. Only if the first and the second amount are equal, no entry is ok. This calculation is implemented via [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform).

```python
df_check = df.withColumnRenamed("count", "count_val") \
    .groupBy("Category", "count_val").count() \
    .groupBy("Category").agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct("count", "count_val")),False).alias("count")) \
    .withColumn("counts", F.expr("if(size(count)==1, array((count[0]['count_val'], 'OK')), \
        transform(count, (x,i)-> if( i == 0 and count[i+1]['count'] <> x['count'], \
        (x['count_val'], 'OK'),(x['count_val'],'Mismatch'))))")) \
    .withColumn("counts", F.explode("counts")) \
    .selectExpr("Category", "counts.col1 as count", "counts.col2 as Check")
```

`df_check` now contains

```
+---------+-----+--------+
| Category|count|   Check|
+---------+-----+--------+
|Category2|    2|      OK|
|Category2|    5|Mismatch|
|Category1|    4|      OK|
+---------+-----+--------+
```

The second step is to join the original `df` and `df_check`:

```python
df.join(df_check, on=["Category", "count"], how="left_outer") \
    .orderBy("Category", "Filename") \
    .select("Category", "Filename", "count", "DistinctCount", "Check") \
    .show()
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+
| Category|Filename|count|DistinctCount|   Check|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+
|Category1|   File1|    4|            1|      OK|
|Category1|   File2|    4|            1|      OK|
|Category1|   File3|    4|            1|      OK|
|Category1|   File4|    4|            1|      OK|
|Category2|   File1|    2|            2|      OK|
|Category2|   File2|    2|            2|      OK|
|Category2|   File3|    2|            2|      OK|
|Category2|   File4|    5|            2|Mismatch|
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+
```